# find command does not find the file in /sys/devices/ recursively

Tags: bash, shell, find, file-search

I'm using `find` to find the file `cpuinfo_max_freq` in the the directory `/sys/devices/`

This is the command I used, it's not showing me any output:

```
find /sys/devices/ -name 'cpuinfo_max_freq'
```

I also tried adding the -L flag to search inside linked directories too, but it doesn't seem to work, And keeps outputting endlessly and never finishes. But doing a find in the root directory (`/`) works fine.

Here's the path to the actual file:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

Comment: "keeps outputting endlessly"? What does it output? Is it permissions denied errors? Do you find the file as expected if you run `find /sys/devices/ -name 'cpuinfo_max_freq' 2>/dev/null`? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` path contains symlink components:

```
$ namei -l /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
f: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
drwxr-xr-x root root /
dr-xr-xr-x root root sys
drwxr-xr-x root root devices
drwxr-xr-x root root system
drwxr-xr-x root root cpu
drwxr-xr-x root root cpu1
lrwxrwxrwx root root cpufreq -> ../cpufreq/policy1
drwxr-xr-x root root   ..
drwxr-xr-x root root   cpufreq
drwxr-xr-x root root   policy1
-r--r--r-- root root cpuinfo_max_freq
```

The canonical path of the corresponding file is:

```
$ readlink -f /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

And that path is among the ones returned by:

```
$ find /sys/devices/ -name 'cpuinfo_max_freq'
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy6/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy7/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

Unless you pass the `-L` option or `-follow` predicate, `find` doesn't follow symlinks when descending the directory trees rooted at the paths you give it as argument.

`find -L` would evantually find it (along with `/sys/devices/system/node/node0/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`, `/sys/devices/system/memory/memory8/node0/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`, `/sys/devices/system/node/node0/subsystem/devices/node0/subsystem/devices/node0/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`..., and an infinity of other paths) but `find` with `-L` would also get lost in `/sys/devices` as `/sys` contains many many symlinks, some of which causing loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify you're looking for a "regular file" (`-type f`):

```bsh
$ find /sys/devices -name 'cpuinfo_max_freq' -type f 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

This works fine on my Debian/RPi OS system

If you're trying it in `macOS`, forget it... `find` is a different animal in `macOS`

Comment: `-type f` doesn’t help `find` find anything; it filters what it does find. Put another way, a given `find` invocation won’t find anything more if you add more tests to it.